# Python Tkinter error: "Label has no __call__method"

Tags: python, tkinter

Im trying to create a Python tkinter login registeration but running into a small issue.

The error message is:

```
self.Label_Name = Label(top, text="What is your username: ")
AttributeError: Label instance has no __call__ method
```

Please can you proof read my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Register:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)

        # Variables to store the entries
        self.VarEntUser = StringVar()
        self.VarEntPass = StringVar()
        self.VarEntRetype = StringVar()

        self.Label_Name = Label(top, text="What is your username: ")
        self.Label_Password = Label(top, text="Enter a password: ")
        self.Label_Retype = Label(top, text="Retype Password: ")

        # Entry fields for the user to enter there details
        self.Ent_Name = Entry(top, textvariable=self.VarEntUser)
        self.Ent_Password = Entry(top, textvariable=self.VarEntPass)
        self.Ent_Retype = Entry(top, textvariable=self.VarEntRetype)

        # Puts all the fields ^, into the window
        self.Label_Name.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        self.Label_Password.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        self.Label_Retype.grid(row=2, sticky=W)

        self.Ent_Password.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.Ent_Retype.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.Ent_Name.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Run the RegisterCheck function
        # submit button which Checks the Entered details then writes the user and   pass to a .txt file
        self.MySubmitButton = Button(top, text='Submit', command=RegisterCheck)
        self.MySubmitButton.pack()

        self.U = raw_input(self.VarEntUser.get())
        self.P = raw_input(self.VarEntPass.get())
        self.R = raw_input(self.VarEntRetype.get())


class LogIn:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.a = StringVar()
        self.b = StringVar()

        self.Label_Log_User1 = Label(top, text='Username:')
        self.Label_Log_Pass = Label(top, text='Password: ')

        self.Ent_User_Log = Entry(top, textvariable=self.a)
        self.Ent_Pass_Log = Entry(top, textvariable=self.b)

        self.Label_Log_User1.grid(row=1)
        self.Pass_Log.grid(row=2)
        self.EntUserLog.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.EntPassLog.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.User = raw_input(self.EntUserLog.get())
        self.Pass = raw_input(self.EntUserLog.get())
        # runs the 'LoginCheck' function
        self.LogInButton = Button(top, text="Log In", command=LogInCheck)
        self.LogInButton.pack()


def LogInCheck(self):
    # Checks if the fields are blanking displaying an error
    if len(self.User) <= 0 and len(self.Pass) <= 0:
        print "Please fill in all fields."
    else:
        pass

    # Checks to see if the user and pass have been created
    if self.User in 'username.txt' and self.Pass in 'password':
        print 'You are now logged in!'
    else:
        print "Log in Failed"


def RegisterCheck(self):
    # Checks if the fields are blank
    if len(self.P) <= 0 and len(self.U) <= 0:
        print "Please fill out all fields."
    else:
        pass
    # Check is the password and the retype match
    if self.P == self.R:
        pass    
    else:
        print "Passwords do not match"

    # After registering write the user and pass to a .txt file     
    with open('username.txt', 'a') as fout:
        fout.write(self.U + '\n')

    with open('password.txt', 'a') as fout:
        fout.write(self.P + '\n')

# Depending on what the user chooses, either log in or register than opens    the specific window

def launch_Register():
    inputDialog = Register(root)
    root.wait_window(inputDialog.top)

def launch_LogIn():
    inputdialog2 = LogIn(root)
    root.wait_window(inputdialog2.top)

root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Choose an option')
label.pack()

loginB = Button(root, text='Log In', command=launch_LogIn)
loginB.pack()

registerB = Button(root, text='Register', command=launch_Register)
registerB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in this line

```
Label = Label(root, text='Choose an option')
```

you define a `Label` called `Label`, thus shadowing the `Label` constructor. Then, then you create the several labels in your `Register` and `Login` classes (triggered by those two buttons), the name `Label` is no longer bound to the constructor, but to that specific label.

Change the name of the label, then it should work. Also, I would advise you to use lower-case names for variables and methods. This alone might help prevent many such errors.

```
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='Choose an option')
label.pack()

loginB = Button(root, text='Log In', command=launch_LogIn)
loginB.pack()

registerB = Button(root, text='Register', command=launch_Register)
registerB.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Note that there are <strike>a few</strike> *many* more problems with your code:

- `StringVar` `a` and `b` should probably be `self.a` and `self.b`
- You are trying to use `raw_input` to get the user input in the `Entry` widgets; this is wrong! Instead, just read the value of the variables to get the values, e.g. instead of `self.User`, use `self.a.get()`
- do not mix `grid` and `pack` layout
- `if self.User in 'username.txt'` will *not* check whether that name is in that file
- `loginCheck` and `registerCheck` should be methods of the respective class

---

Once I'm at it, here's (part of) my version of your code, to help you getting started:

```
class Register:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        top = self.top = Toplevel(parent)
        self.var_user = StringVar()
        self.var_pass = StringVar()
        self.var_retype = StringVar()

        Label(top, text="What is your username: ").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
        Label(top, text="Enter a password: ").grid(row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(top, text="Retype Password: ").grid(row=2, sticky=W)
        Entry(top, textvariable=self.var_user).grid(row=0, column=1)
        Entry(top, textvariable=self.var_pass).grid(row=1, column=1)
        Entry(top, textvariable=self.var_retype).grid(row=2, column=1)
        Button(top, text='Submit', command=self.registerCheck).grid(row=3)

    def registerCheck(self):
        u, p, r = self.var_user.get(), self.var_pass.get(), self.var_retype.get()
        if p and u:
            if p == r:
                logins[u] = p
            else:
                print "Passwords do not match"
        else:
            print "Please fill out all fields."

class LogIn:

    # analogeous to Register; try to figure this out xourself

def launch_Register():
    inputDialog = Register(root)
    root.wait_window(inputDialog.top)

def launch_LogIn():
    inputDialog = LogIn(root)
    root.wait_window(inputDialog.top)

logins = {}
root = Tk()
Label(root, text='Choose an option').pack()
Button(root, text='Log In', command=launch_LogIn).pack()
Button(root, text='Register', command=launch_Register).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Note that I changed the login "database" from files to a dictionary to keep things simple and to focus on the Tkinter problems. Of course, neither a simple dictionary nor a plain-text file is an appropriate way to store login information.

Also, I put the creation and the layout of the GUI widgets on one line. In this case this is possible since we do not need a reference to those widgets, but beware never to do e.g. `self.label = Label(...).grid(...)`, as this will bind `self.label` to the result of `grid`, and not to the actual `Label`.

Finally, this will still print all the messages to the standard output. Instead, you should add another `Label` for that, or open a message dialogue, but this is left as an excercise to the reader...

Comment: hey thanks i fixed up everything but when i click on register or login it just freezes it dosnt open a new window?

Comment: @tobias_k: it freezes because you are calling `raw_input`. It's waiting for you to type something in the command window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I already found that bit. See my update(s). Turns out there are _lots_ of other problems with the code, and that `Label` thing was just the tip of the iceberg...